# Let $(u_n)$ be a bounded sequence of real numbers such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty} u_{n+1}-u_n^2=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $(u_n)$ be a bounded sequence of real numbers such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty} u_{n+1}-u_n^2=0$. What can we say about $(u_n)$.

Noticing the fact that $(u_n)$ is a bounded sequence, we can use the Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem to say that $0$ and $1$ are the only points where $(u_n)$ can converges. Can we notice more ?

Comment: So you proved that the sequence converges and the limit value is either 0 or 1?

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen that's i guess exactly what i need to show, what i've shown up to now is that the sequence may converge to 0, or 1, or there exists two subsequences, one converges to 1, and the other to 0, and thus the sequence diverges

Comment: I can prove the convergence of this question but I'm curious how you apply Bozalno to this question.  Can you show me?

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen the theorem is applied when the sequence is bounded, which is the case here. Thus let l the limit of the convergent subsequent (which exists owing to Bolzano), we have $l-l^2=0$ then $l = 0$ or $l = 1$.

Comment: Are you sure about that? For any subsequence $(u_{n_k})$ , $u_{ n_k+1}$ is not necessarily belong to that subsequence

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen yes i got it wrong :(

Answer (score 2):

First, we show that $(u_n)_n$ cannot have a subsequence converging to any $L\not\in \{0,1\}.$ Second, we show this implies $u_n$ converges to $0$ or to $1.$

First, suppose $L$ is a limit of the sequence with $0\ne L\ne 1.$ Then $L^2,L^4,L^8,L^{16}$ (etc.) are limits too, and the sequence is bounded, so $0<|L|<1.$ Then $L'=L^{2^k}$ is also a limit for some $k\in \Bbb N$ such that $0<L'<|L|/8$. Take $m_1\in \Bbb N$ such that $n>m_1\implies |u_n^2-u_{n+1}|<|L|/8.$ Take $m_2\in \Bbb N$ with $m_2>m_1$ and $0<|u_{m_2}-L'|<L'.$

Now (1). $|u_{m_2}|<|L|/4.$ (2). If $n\ge m_2$ and if $|u_n|<|L|/4$ then $$|u_{n+1}|<|u_n^2|+|L|/8<|L|^2/16+|L|/8<|L|/16+|L|/8<|L|/4.$$ So by induction on $n\ge m_2$, we have $n\ge m_2\implies |u_n|<|L|/4.$ This contracts the assumption that $L$ is a limit of the sequence.

Second, by the first part, take $n_1\in \Bbb N$ such that $\forall n\in \Bbb N\,(\,n>n_1\implies |u_{n+1}-u_n^2| <1/4\,).$

Take $n_2\in \Bbb N$  such that $\forall n\in \Bbb N\,(\,n>n_2\implies (\,|u_n-1|<1/5\lor |u_n|<1/5\,).$

Suppose that $\{n\in \Bbb N: |u_n-1|<1/5\}$ and $\{n\in \Bbb N: |u_n|<1/5\}$ are both infinite sets. Take some (any) $n>\max (n_1,n_2)$ such that $|u_n-1|<1/5$. Now let $n'$ be the least $m>n$ such that $|u_m|<1/5.$ Then $n'-1\ge n>n_2$ and by def'n of $n'$ we have $\neg (|u_{n'-1}|<1/5),$ so $|u_{n'-1}-1|<1/5.$ Hence, since also $n'-1\ge n>n_1,$ therefore $$ 16/25=(1-1/5)^2< |u_{n'-1}^2|<|u_{n'}|+1/4< 1/5 + 1/4$$ which is absurd.

Therefore $u_n$ converges to $0$ or $u_n$ converges to $1.$

Comment: Can you say something about how to find $n_2$?

Comment: Same question, how can you be sure of the existence of $n_2$ ?

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen . $n_2$ exists because the set  $S=\{n\in \Bbb N: u_n\not\in (-1/5,1/5)\cup (4/5,6/5)\}$ is finite. If $S$ were infinite then, since $(u_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a bounded sequence, there would be a subsequence of $(u_n)_{n\in S}$ converging to a limit $L $with $0\ne L\ne 1$, but that would violate $\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n^2-u_{n+1}=0.$

Comment: @ArcticChar . See my comment immediately above.

Comment: How can it violate?   $u_{n_k}$  converging to $L$ does not imply the $u_{n_{k}+1}$ converging to $L$

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen. Yes. I omitted the 1st part, which  I have added.

Comment: @ArcticChar .Yes. I omitted the 1st part, which  I have added.

Comment: What if we allow $u_n\in\Bbb C$ instead?

Answer (score 1):

Let $m= \liminf u_n$. Because $(u_n)$ is bounded, $m$ cannot be infinity. 
Let$(u_{n_k})$ be a subsequence of $(u_n)$ such that $$\lim_{k \rightarrow+\infty} u_{n_k}=m$$
So we have
$$0 = \lim_{k}( u_{n_k+1}-u_{n_k}^2) \ge m-m^2 $$
Hence $m \ge 1$ or $m \le 0$

---

If $m \ge 1$, let $M=\limsup u_n \ge \liminf u_n=m  $. Similarly, we can show that 
$$M-M^2 \ge 0$$
which means $0 \le M \le 1$, hence $M=m=1$. Thus
$$\lim u_n =1$$

---

If $m \le 0$, wee see that 
$$0 = \lim_{k} ( u_{n_k}- u_{n_{k-1}}^2 ) \le \lim_k u_{n_k} =m $$
Thus $m=0$, or
$$\liminf u_n = 0$$

Choosing any $\epsilon \in (0,1/8)$
Because $\lim u_n-u_n^2=0$,  there is a $N_1$ such that $$ u_n-u_n^2<\epsilon \quad \forall n >N_1 $$

Because $\liminf u_n = 0$, there is a $N_2>N_1$ such that $u_n>-\epsilon$ for all $n \ge N_2$ and
$$|u_{N_2}|<\epsilon/2$$
We'll prove now that $$u_n <\frac{1-\sqrt{1- 4\epsilon}}{2}=: a_{\epsilon}$$ for all $n\ge N_2$.
Indeed, $ u_n < \frac{2\epsilon}{1+\sqrt{1-4\epsilon}}= a_{\epsilon} $ with $n=N_2$
If $u_k<a_{\epsilon}$ for  some $n=k \ge N_2$, we see that
because  $ k \ge N_2 \ge N_1$,
$$u_{k+1}-a_{\epsilon}\le u_k^2+\underbrace{\epsilon-a_{\epsilon}}_{=-a_{\epsilon}^2} = \underbrace{(u_k-a_{\epsilon})}_{<0}\underbrace{(u_k+a_{\epsilon})}_{ > 0 \text{ because } u_k>-\epsilon} <0$$
Hence
$$u_n < a_{\epsilon}$$ for all $n\ge N_2$.
Because $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, this implies that $M=\limsup u_n \le 0=m$, thus
$$\lim u_n= 0$$

*Side note*: Boundedness is not necessary anyways, we can always show it by using the given convergence.